Single SSO with multiple bot using Bot Framework SDK
We currently have a bot (hosted in teams as an app) which calls the rest api (api/messages) to get details. We use TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware for SSO using OAuthPrompt and use ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication for Appid authentication.
We want to support additional bot (create new app in Teams) and use the same end point and code so we can do certain customize based on the incoming request. This will avoid us hosting another web service and create new project.
I tried looking and see that I can use ICredentialProvider to authenticate appid, though as per MS this is obsolete. But to do SSO i m unable to get success, I created MultiBotTeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware and instantiate TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware by passing connectionName based on the incoming request. We will have 2 connection now and hence we will create 2 TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware instances based on the connection name, than we will call OnTurnAsync event. Once that is done we will invoke OAuthPrompt which should not show user login prompt as we already have injected TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware which should take care.
Currently we do inject TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware as part of AdapterWithErrorHandler and SSO works fine but when i'm, trying to implement for multi bot than it fails.
Can someone please provide help on this?
Use(new TeamsSSOTokenExchangeMiddleware(storage, configuration["ConnectionName"]));


We are checking this with engineering team, we will update you soon

ok thanks @Nivedipa-MSFT

It is not possible for multiple bots to use the same AAD app for SSO because AAD only allows one Application ID URI/Resource URI to be specified for an AAD app.
